# Can I assume that accept(3) returns IPv4 address if I apply it to an IPv4 socket?

Tags: unix, network-programming, posix, ipv6, ipv4

Let `s` be a file descriptor of a socket made by `socket(PF_INET, ...)`.

If I call `accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, ...)`, where `addr` is of type `struct sockaddr_in`, can I assume that the format of the returned address is IPv4, i.e.,

`addr.sin_family == AF_INET` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [The Open Group's](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/accept.html) description:

> The `accept()` function shall extract the first connection on the queue
>   of pending connections, **create a new socket with the same socket
>   type protocol and address family as the specified socket**, and
>   allocate a new file descriptor for that socket.